# Extending Office Ribbon with listbox

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, ribbon

I added an *EditBox* to an Office Ribbon (adding controls is ok). 
I would like adding a resulting list bellow to it - see the Outlook's sample bellow. How can I do it? Is it a separate windows form?

*EditBox* has only one eventhandler for TextChanged event. It provides the *sender* object an a *RibbonControlEventArgs*. I didn't find any position property inside the sender or in the event args. How could I know where should I display it? Do you have guys any advise?

[image: Sample from Outlook]